# Getting Liblouis to run and translate on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, linux, xhtml, raspberry-pi

I feel kind of dumb for asking this but I am really lost and don't know quite where to go anymore (mostly I can not find a clear answer wherever I look).

I am trying to run Liblouis Braille formator (http://liblouis.org/) on a raspberry pi. I am fairly certain it is installed (in the right place, I am not certain) but I don't know quite how to access it or use it in any way. Either in command line or python or whatever.

I am not very familiar with systems outside of java, python, c, and c++ on a windows so I am getting kind of lost. Any help at all would be wonderful, even a nudge in a direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not super-familiar with liblouis myself, but these seems to be the commands available if you've installed it correctly: `lou_allround`, `lou_checkhyphens`, `lou_checktable`, `lou_debug`, `lou_translate`. What you want is probably `lou_translate`:

```
➜ lou_translate --help
Usage: lou_translate [OPTIONS] TABLE[,TABLE,...]
Translate whatever is on standard input and print it on standard
output. It is intended for large-scale testing of the accuracy of
Braille translation and back-translation.

  -h, --help          display this help and exit
  -v, --version       display version information and exit
  -f, --forward       forward translation using the given table
  -b, --backward      backward translation using the given table
                      If neither -f nor -b are specified forward translation
                      is assumed

Report bugs to john.boyer@abilitiessoft.com.
liblouis home page: <http://code.google.com/p/liblouis/>
```

You will need to pick a translation table appropriate for your language (I'm not sure which ones are most used, there's several to choose from), and probably also a display table, depending on what you plan to use it for. For instance:

```
➜ echo "Getting Liblouis to run and translate on a Raspberry Pi" | lou_translate en-gb-g1.utb 
,getting ,liblouis to run and translate on a ,raspberry ,pi

➜ echo "Getting Liblouis to run and translate on a Raspberry Pi" | lou_translate unicode.dis,en-gb-g1.utb
\x2820\x281b\x2811\x281e\x281e\x280a\x281d\x281b \x2820\x2807\x280a\x2803\x2807\x2815\x2825\x280a\x280e \x281e\x2815 \x2817\x2825\x281d \x2801\x281d\x2819 \x281e\x2817\x2801\x281d\x280e\x2807\x2801\x281e\x2811 \x2815\x281d \x2801 \x2820\x2817\x2801\x280e\x280f\x2803\x2811\x2817\x2817\x283d \x2820\x280f\x280a
```

The latter sequence of unicode codepoints translates to:

`⠠⠛⠑⠞⠞⠊⠝⠛ ⠠⠇⠊⠃⠇⠕⠥⠊⠎ ⠞⠕ ⠗⠥⠝ ⠁⠝⠙ ⠞⠗⠁⠝⠎⠇⠁⠞⠑ ⠕⠝ ⠁ ⠠⠗⠁⠎⠏⠃⠑⠗⠗⠽ ⠠⠏⠊`

Hope this helps :)